# How to find items with null revision

Tags: publishing-service

I'm installing  Sitecore Publishing Service 3.1 Update-4 and getting this error when attempting to publish.

Error in the *TreeNodeSourceProducer*

```
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: A revision cannot be an empty Guid.
Parameter name: revision
```

anyone knows a good way to determine what item(s) is creating the issue?

Comment: I believe you'll need to dig into SQL to find that.

Comment: I will suggest you run "clean up database" from control panel and try again.